# How can Alexa be set up to support multiple todo list apps?

Tags: speech-recognition, to-do, voice-command

**Note that this question is *not* asking for how to add additional lists :) .**

So I'm trying to setup my Alexa to support both my home needs (mainly a todo list and shopping list) and my work ones. However:

- it seems like you can only have 1 main todo list skill assigned via the app.
- I want to support more than 2 custom lists (todoist would be ideal but can't use custom lists, so is capped at 2).
- I'd like some/all of the custom work lists to be private/separate (this could be privacy via a different app, it's more for ease than for secure purposes). This is the need I'm struggling to incorporate.

I've used and am happy to use a variety of todo skills, and currently outside of Alexa I use Todoist, Evernote, Trello.

Intents:

- Alexa, add XXX to todo list (personal) <-- I can currently do this with the Todoist skill.
- Alexa, add XXX to shopping list (personal) <-- I can currently do this with the Todoist skill.
- Alexa, add XXX to my work list  (private) <-- **can't see a way to do this without losing the Todoist.**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can a human identify what isn't clear about the question? :)